# Linux Arch Xorg xf86EnableIOPorts failed

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, desktop-environments

I recently installed Arch, as a desktop environment I chose Budgie desktop and I would like to run without any display manager.

But sometimes I encounter an issue where when I log in and exec startx, it tries to initialize the desktop environment, I can even see my desktop background for a second but then it crashes to the terminal again.
It shows up a picture with sad smile telling:
`"Oh no!" "Something has gone wrong."`

The only message I get in terminal is:

```
Fatal server error:
Xf86EnableIOPorts: Failed to set IOPO for I/O (operation not permitted)
```

Actually I found out the failure occurs before this error. Sometimes this error even shows up when the Xorg starts up normally and I log out...

**I can startx without any problem when running as root!**
(The only difference is different configuration of my theme etc..)

Here is what my `.xinitrc` looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi


if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"
fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi


# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
 for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
  [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
 done
 unset f
fi


#export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME-classic:GNOME
#export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=classic
#exec gnome-session --session=gnome-classic

export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Budgie:GNOME
exec budgie-desktop

#twm &
#xclock -geometry 50x50-1+1 &
#xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &
#xterm -geometry 80x20+494-0 &
#exec xterm -geometry 80x66+0+0 -name login
```

The system file in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` looks exactly the same.

Here is my Xorg log: http://pastebin.com/ViA4xUTD

I'm running on ASUS Zenbook ux303 laptop with Intel Skylage 6500U and with NVIDIA 940M GPU. I don't know if it is relevant information or not but I think I think it's worth it to mention.

Comment: In case this Budgie wrapper has some issue, does `exec gnome-session` instead of `exec budgie-desktop` (and without `export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Budgie:GNOME`) work?

Comment: @TomYan I don't know what happend over night but when I turned on my laptop this morning, I could see loading kernel and then black screen only. I started the kernel with nomodeset parameter and I can now log in but when I startx, it throws me no screens found. So now I have to solve this issue first.

Comment: I just got this with Arch Linux VM in Hyper-V and fixed it by adding the user to the `video` group.